# SQL tables containing mostly the same fields?

Tags: sql

I have to design a database for storing information about various items. Most of that information would be very similar like "name" but each type of item has some unique properties varying in count, for example one would have "color" while another would have "weight" and "height".

I tried to make a separate table for each item, but this makes those tables mostly the same and retrieving all items from all tables cumbersome. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @user11778750 You could set up a many-to-many relationship between items and attributes, then have a join/junction table which holds the value of each attribute and an associated foreign key to the type of attribute and an assocaited foreign key to the item.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions.

(1) You can just list all the possible attributes and have them be `NULL` when they do not apply.

(2) You can have all the common attributes in a single table with a primary key.  Then have each other type of entity store the columns specific to the entity.

(3) You can have separate tables for each entity and just repeat the common items.

(4) You can use an entity-attribute-value (EAV) model.  That is a table with an entity id, column name and column value.

(5) You can use a hybrid EAV model, when you have a central table with the common attributes and an EAV table with the additional attributes.

(6) You can store the values as a JSON, XML, or similar encoded column.

There may be other options as well.  Is one of these better than the others?  Gosh, I think I've used all of them under different circumstances and in different databases.

So, there may be a "better" way under specific circumstances, but your question doesn't provide any specific information for making such a judgement.